# В чём разница?

Tags: c#

Привет ХэшКод, скажите в чём разница?

```
button1.Text = "Здорова молодые";
```

и

```
this.button1.Text = "Здорова молодые";
```

Answer (score 5):

Покажу на примере:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int id;

    public MyClass(int id)
    {
        id = 123;
        id = id;
    }
}
```

Вы можете без запуска данного кода со 100% уверенность сказать, какое значение будет у поля `id` после инициализации объекта? Завидую, если можете.

Использование `this` гарантирует, что будет использована именно та переменная, которая относится к классу, а не локальная или какая-либо другая. По-моему отсюда и пошла "мода" давать приватным полям имена начинающиеся с символа _ `(private int _id;)`, хотя я могу ошибаться.

P.S. обращения выделяются запятыми - "Здорова, молодые"

Comment: не будет никакого значения =D